# Joint probability distribution of a coin toss

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> A fair coin is tossed four times. Let the random variable $X$ denote the number of heads in the first 3 tosses, and let the random variable $Y$ denote the number of heads in the last 3 tosses.  What is the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$?

The solution is the following table, which I am having trouble with.

$$
  \begin{array}{l|llll}
      X \backslash Y
    & 0
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    \hline
      0
    & 1/16
    & 1/16
    & 0
    & 0
    \\
      1
    & 1/16
    & 3/16
    & 2/16
    & 0
    \\
      2
    & 0
    & 2/16
    & 3/16
    & 1/16
    \\
      3
    & 0
    & 0
    & 1/16
    & 1/16
  \end{array}
$$
(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac01R.png)).

I do not understand $(1,1)$. Where do they get $3/16$ from? The only possibility of only $1$ head in the first $3$ tosses and only $1$ in the last $3$ tosses is HTTH, hence it should be $1/16$?

Furthermore I do not understand $(2,2)$. Where do they get $3/16$ from? The only possibility of only $2$ heads in both the first $3$ tosses and the last $3$ tosses is THHT, hence it should also be $1/16$?

Comment: For (1,1) you can also have THTT and TTHT and for (2,2) HTHH and HHTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1,1)$, note that in contrary to what you are writing, 
$$ \{X=1, Y=1\} = \{HTTH, THTT, TTHT\} $$
and for $(2,2)$ the same trick works 
$$ \{X=2, Y=2\} = \{THHT, HHTH, HTHH\} $$

Answer (score 1):

For (1, 1), you may have HTTH, THTT, TTHT.

For (2, 2), you may have THHT, HTHH, HHTH